# Docker container ssh error: ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, docker, openssh

I am trying to set up an Ubuntu container with `openssh-server` so I can ssh into it from the host. I know it's not the standard way of doing it but I really want to have `ssh`.

This is my `Dockerfile`

```
# Select base image
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# Set the current working directory
WORKDIR /home

# Update the system, download any packages essential for the project
RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y git build-essential make gcc vim net-tools iputils-ping ca-certificates openssh-server libc6:i386 libstdc++6:i386

# Allow ssh root login
RUN echo "root:root" | chpasswd

# RUN rpl "PermitRootLogin prohibit-password" "PermitRootLogin yes" /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN sed -i 's/prohibit-password/yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

RUN cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh

RUN chown -R root:root /root/.ssh;chmod -R 700 /root/.ssh

RUN echo “StrictHostKeyChecking=no” >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config

RUN service ssh restart


# Open port 22 so linked containers can see it
EXPOSE 22

# Import any additional files into the environment (from the host)
ADD otherfile .
```

I start the container with `docker run -t -d -p 2222:22` but whenever I try to ssh into it I always end up getting the error `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`:

```
➜ ssh -v -p 2222 root@localhost /bin/bash
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/giorgio/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/giorgio/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/giorgio/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/giorgio/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/giorgio/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/giorgio/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/giorgio/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/giorgio/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/giorgio/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/giorgio/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/giorgio/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Does anyone knwo what causes this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `RUN service ssh restart`

This runs an ssh service restart (well actually a start) during the image creation phase, not in the future running container. There is no `CMD` nor `ENTRYPOINT` in you `Dockerfile` so it defaults to the one(s) configured in your base image ([which is bash](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/bfd753a747344ff1c6838a2c91ff0606e936f0d0/xenial/Dockerfile))

In other words, there is no ssh daemon running when you start your container. A temporary solution is to launch an exec command on the running container: `docker exec your_container_name service ssh start`

To fix the issue correctly you need to instruct the image it should start sshd when a container is created (see the [dockerize an ssh service](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/) at docker docs). In short:

- remove the `RUN service ssh restart` line
- add the two next lines

```
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
CMD ['/usr/sbin/sshd', '-D']
```

- rebuild your image, launch a new container, ssh and enjoy.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the link! I have tried making that change but now the container dies as soon as it is started, exiting with code 127.

Comment: Ok, seems like it was only a problem with the order of the lines in the Dockerfile